# Alert not showing on the modal that is presenting

Tags: swift, xcode

On a view Controller when I click on the guard button -->

```swift
@IBAction func guardTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let vc = guardViewController.instanceFromNib()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So In this guardViewController which is a presenting modal, I want to show an alert message when I click on the close button on guardViewController.

```swift
@IBAction func closeTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are You Sure", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let proceedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed", style: .destructive) { (action) in

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(proceedAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        //
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: (sender as AnyObject).bounds.midX, y: (sender as AnyObject).bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = [.any]
    }
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Present on root controller like this : ```UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)```

Comment: I tried what you said.Still not working.

Comment: Probably a stupid question on my part, but WHY are you reaching into `UIApplication` to present a modal popup? There are several other ways to do this. Both generically (as in something available to the entire app) and specifically to one view controller. I've never seen code like this `appDelegate.present`. Are you trying to deal with something similar to a login popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting simple Alert with this Alert helper:

```
struct Alert {

static func showErrorAlertWithOk(on vc: UIViewController, withTitle: String, andMessage: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: withTitle, message: andMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) {_ in }
    alert.addAction(action)
    vc.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

}

Then use is as folows:

```
Alert.showErrorAlertWithOk(on: yourViewController, withTitle: "SampleAlert", andMessage: "YourMessage")
```

Comment: This is not helping too. I want to show an alert on a view controller which is presenting modally on another view controller.

Comment: Aha. Just saw this comment! That's not easily (and like simply) *not* possible. Think through two things, and maybe something will help us help you. First, what *exactly* are you trying to do (and why) and can you give us enough code that we can duplicate your issue? Second, can you provide a better description on *why* you are (a) trying to create a stack where (I think) you want AppDelegate to present something on this stack (VC1 >> VC2 >> VC3 modally)? That's what I can glean from your question - where is this VC stack wrong?